# information_schema.TABLES with server choise

Tags: sql, sql-server

How i can check list of tables of db on another server?

Example:

```
SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='DB_NAME'
*and SERVER_NAME = 'SERVER_NAME'*
```

Comment: use Linked Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine

Comment: or even easier is to connect to that server and query directly !